# SQL 2016 RC3 R Services Error

Tags: sql-server, r, sql-server-2016

Many of the current questions are with previous versions of the RC or CTP. This is using the latest docs and build for RC3.

I am running their [sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt696069.aspx) to verify everything is working:

```
exec sp_execute_external_script  @language =N'R',
@script=N'OutputDataSet<-InputDataSet',  
@input_data_1 =N'select 1 as hello'
with result sets (([hello] int not null));
go
```

Here is the error:

```
Msg 39021, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Unable to launch runtime for 'R' script. Please check the configuration of the 'R' runtime.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An external script error occurred: 
Unable to launch the runtime. ErrorCode 0x80004005: .
Msg 11536, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1 result set(s), but the statement only sent 0 result set(s) at run time.
```

I had previously uninstalled RC0 on this box, otherwise there is nothing else going on with sql 2016. It is a named instance (SQL2016) because there is a 2014 install on the box.

The logs for RServer indicate that everything was found and installed correctly. The 'execute external scripts' setting is enabled. I'm not sure what else to do. Any ideas would be helpful. I just want to see this in action in our own environment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm [Uninstalling previous versions of R components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653951.aspx#Anchor_2) is completed including the removal of references to the R extensions:

RegisterRExt.exe /UNINSTALL

If you enabled R integration on a named instance, specify the instance name after /instance:

RegisterRExt.exe /UNINSTALL /INSTANCE:[instancename]

Comment: Hi Arun, I ran those commands as part of my troubleshooting. I've seen that elsewhere. I used the RegisterRExt.exe that was in the RC3 installed files. The logs indicate that everything succeeded.

Comment: Can you see any error messages in following log files for R?


"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\Log\ExtensibilityLog\rlauncher.log"


"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\Log\ExtensibilityLog\EXTLAUNCHERRORLOG"