# Error: "External script execution failed as extensibility environment is not ready yet....." in Sql 2016 with R service installed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I install R-service in SQL 2016 Developer Edition, checked the installation and get the following report from the setup tool:

[image: Installed Components of SQL 2016 including R Service]

To test R Service, I run the following script:

```
    sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1;  
    RECONFIGURE; 
    go

    exec sp_execute_external_script  @language =N'R',    
    @script=N'OutputDataSet<-InputDataSet',      
    @input_data_1 =N'select 1 as hello'    
    with result sets (([hello] int not null));    
    go
```

And get the following error:

```
 Msg 39025, Level 16, State 1, Server WIN10, Line 1
 External script execution failed as extensibility environment is not ready yet. Retry the operation when the server is fully started.

 Msg 11536, Level 16, State 1, Server WIN10, Line 14
 EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1    result set(s), but the statement only sent 0 result set(s) at run time.
```

I installed the update of sql server 2016
[SQLServer2016-KB3164674-x64 update](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/E/F/1EF6D06B-D1D3-4E98-A727-00D9787AE572/SQL16RTMCU1/x64/SQLServer2016-KB3164674-x64.exe)

I followed the steps in the post:
  [SQL 2016 RC3 R Services Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770607/sql-2016-rc3-r-services-error),
and [r-in-sql-server-2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148268/r-in-sql-server-2016)
but still the error exist

As, you see in the figure, R service is reported as No configured
In spite of I executed the script:

```
  sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1;
```

- How To Configure R-Service  to be reported correctly.
- How to resolve the above error.

**Update:**

Based on the response  of "Umachandar - Microsoft":

SQL Server 2016 is running on Windows 10.

I checked  SQL errorlog and find the following errors:

```
 Unknown,SQL failed to boot extensibility for error code 0xa.
 Unknown,Error: 39002<c/> Severity: 16<c/> State: 1.
```

Also, I found the same extensibility error in Windows 10 Application Event:

```
 Log        Windows NT (Application)
 Source     MSSQLSERVER
 Category       (2)
 Event      39002
 Computer       xxxx
 Message
 SQL failed to boot extensibility for error code 0xa.
```

**Update 2:**

**Now it's working** after applying the procedures in the answer and comments of Umachandar - Microsoft.

- Modified rlauncher.config in the folder E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn

  ```
  WORKING_DIRECTORY=c:\ExtensibilityData
  ```
- Using the Junction tool and  run the script:

  ```
  junction64.exe c:\ExtensibilityData "E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData"
  ```
- Restart the service: MSSQLLaunchpad
- Executing the sql script in my post , return 1

Many thank to Umachandar - Microsoft for advice and support.

Comment: I experienced a similar problem which I could solve by installing the latest cumulative update CU3 on SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that SQL Server was unable to boot the extensibility environment during service startup.

Are you running Windows 10? Can you check the SQL errorlog for any errors? For example, check for below error:

SQL failed to boot extensibility for error code 0x%lx

And any error that mentions Launchpad or extensibility. You can also email me the SQL errorlog and I will take a look.

--

The error message indicates that R Services was not installed successfully when you installed RTM. You can use the following workaround to get the system into a working state:

1. Merge the registry keys from this post first on the SQL Server machine (If you installed SQL Server as a named instance then you have to update MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER to match your installation)
2. Uninstall CU2 (you can do this from control panel under "View Installed Updates")
3. Run SQL Server setup from control panel and remove the "R Services (In-Database)" feature
4. Run SQL Server setup from control and add the "R Services (In-Database)" feature again to your instance
5. Apply CU2 if needed

--

> Registry Key #1

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\SRO]
"SRO_1"="3.2.2.803"
"SRO_2"="3.2.2.12000"
```

> Registry Key #2

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\SRS]
"SRS_1"="8.0.3"
"SRS_2"="8.0.3.12000"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm running Windows 10, and found the extensibility error. I updated my question with these information.

Comment: See the workaround I posted for steps to correct the issue.

Comment: I applied all steps and the problem is partially resolved. R service (in database)  is configured correctly and MSSQLLaunchpad is  running.
When trying to execute the sql script  in my post , I get the following error: 
Unable to communicate with the runtime for 'R' script. Please check the requirements of 'R' runtime. STDERR message(s) from external script: Fatal error: cannot create 'R_TempDir'. 
I reacched the page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3103286, but can't help. How to resolve the new issue?

Comment: BTW, the update that i applied is: SQLServer2016-KB3164674-x64. I will download the new update CU2 .Can this update resolve the creation of  'R_TempDir'?

Comment: The R_TempDir issue is due to 8dot3 name generation not enabled on the volume. See the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653951.aspx and section "Launchpad service cannot be started". One possible workaround without reinstall is to use sysinternals JUNCTION.EXE tool to create a directory (D:\RTemp) that is mapped to the ExtensiblityData directory. You can then modify RLauncher.config file to point to the D:\RTemp directory instead. My recommendation would be to set the 8dot3name property on volume, remove R-Services & install.

Comment: Thank you very much, Now it's working after applying your last comment. I update my post with the details.